# What does solubility limit mean in practical terms?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

I am not really a chemist guy so please bear with me. Glycerol monolaurate has an upper limit of solubility in water of 20 μg/mL, which is enough for my experiment. Does this mean that no matter how much glycerol monolaurate I add to water the concentration will always stay at 20 μg/mL? Glycerol monolaurate is in powder form so does this mean that the powder would flow on top of water and the concentration of 20 μg/mL glycerol monolaurate would be in the water below?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) If 20 micrograms / ml is the upper solubility limit and you added less than 20 micrograms the solution could be less concentrated but a concentration higher than 20 micrograms / ml H2O can't be achieved.

Q2) No more than 20 micrograms of glycerol monolaurate will dissolve in 1 ml of water so if more than 20 micrograms was added the remaining undissolved powder would stay separated in some way (eg. precipitate) which could be filtered (as @MaxW has stated), or a colloidal suspension could also form. If more than 20 micrograms / ml were to be used the supernatant (GML/H2O layer) could be estimated to be 20 micrograms/ml) after filtration.

Comment: It seems that the density is just below 1.00 for glycerol monolaurate , so the undissolved portion will float. If it had a very fine particle size you might be able to get some sort of colloidal suspension. // There real notion here is two phases if you add more than 20 micrograms per mL. A liquid phase that contains water and the dissolved glycerol monolaurate, and a solid phase that is the undissolved solid glycerol monolaurate.

Comment: @MaxW yes I agree, I haven't made this solution before so I don't know if it separates cleanly or not. Ill edit the emulsion part (:

Comment: You can't really "emulsify" a solid. An emulsion is for two liquids. So the excess solid either floats, sinks, or forms a colloidal suspension - or possibly some combination due to particle size variations, wettability, and surface tension.

Comment: @MaxW yes the colloidal suspension was what I meant ..

Comment: Thanks MaxW and Joel. The below poster stated that the concentration will increase.  I assume this is wrong?

Comment: Must be referring to the overall concentration of the GML in the container not dissolved in solution , maybe the colloidal suspension?